# Send keys to a terminal buffer

Tags: vimscript, neovim

I want to map a keyboard shortcut to execute the last command in a terminal buffer that I have open.

I've made some progress: I am storing the buffer's channel id correctly but when I try to send keys to the terminal (up arrow and enter) they always appear as literal characters in the terminal rather than actually going to the previous command and executing it.

```
" remember the chan id (buffer id) of the last terminal buffer
augroup Terminal
  au!
  au TermOpen * let g:last_terminal_chan_id = b:terminal_job_id
augroup END


" WIP: doesn't work yet
function! REPLSend()
    " the following commented out lines were taken from another plugin that sends keys to a terminal - it doesn't seem to work
    " let isnormal = mode() ==# 'n'
    " let curwin = winnr()
    " exe "sb " . g:last_terminal_chan_id
    " call cursor('$', 1)
    " exe curwin . 'wincmd w'
    " if isnormal
    "     stopinsert
    " endif
    " call chansend(g:last_terminal_chan_id, '<Up>' . '\n')
    call term_sendkeys(g:last_terminal_chan_id, "i\<Up>\<cr>")
endfunction

command! REPLSendLine call REPLSend()

nnoremap <silent> <f5> :REPLSendLine<cr>
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Can you clarify "appearing as literal characters"? The help says `{keys} are translated as key sequences. For example, "\<c-x>"
  means the character CTRL-X.`, so I would expect this to "work"

Comment: If under bash then it's enough to execute "!-1"

Comment: @Matt `!!` too...

Comment: @D.BenKnoble the characters "i\<Up>\<cr>" show up as terminal input. Nothing is executed. I tried some other combinations to the exact same effect: eg "<Up><CR>"

Comment: Did you try inserting them literally (with control-V)?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I don't understand. Why would I do that? It would just be a "<" followed by a "U", then "p" etc. characters. I need the up arrow and the enter key executed in the terminal.

Comment: Control-v then hit up, etc

Comment: Ctrl-v to enter literal mode doesn't work in a terminal buffer it seems. Ctrl-v will insert a ^  character. If you meant something like this: `call chansend(g:last_terminal_chan_id, 'control-V<Up><cr>')` that behaves the same way as everything else, literally writing "control-V<Up><cr>" instead of pressing the special keys.

Comment: For vim. (not neovim). https://balki.me/posts/vim-stt/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't get the up arrow key working, it seems tricky and I don't think it's the best way. But thanks to @thunderbeef's answer I got the enter key working, and a solution I'm happy with:

```
    call chansend(g:last_terminal_chan_id, "!!\<cr>")
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't have `term_sendkeys()` in my `neovim` instance, so I'll use `chandsend()` in my example. Also, the `i` is unnecessary, since this function can't put you into insert mode.

Now, regarding your problem. `"\<Up>"` does indeed have some unexpected behavior inside double quotes. But, I managed to work around it like this:

1. Open `vim` preemptively to not get error on load.
2. While in terminal, start by writing `echo -n '' >> ~/.vimrc`, then put cursor between quotes and press `control-v` followed by `Up`, then `enter` to execute your command.
3. Reload `.vimrc` with `:e!`, delete the last line with literal `Up` sequence, and `p` it wherever you want (in this case, into `chansend` function).

**Upd:** Another way: enter keys by hex code directly in vim:

1. Find out your `Up` key byte sequence in terminal by piping it to `hexdump -C` (same method with echo as described above). This is important, because `Up` key may produce different sequences based on your `$TERM` value, shell, and system-global key remappings. Here's what mine looks like:

```
    echo -n '^[OA' | hexdump -C
    6 00000000  1b 4f 41                                          |.OA|
    5 00000003
```

2. Enter every byte in vim by pressing `C-v`, followed by `x`, and then hex code. E.g. `C-v x 1 b` for first byte, and so on...

This seem to work correctly:

```
call chansend(b:terminal_job_id, '^[OA' . "\<cr>")
```

Do not try to copy code from here, though. You need to get actual literal `Up` sequence from your shell.

**Upd.2:** Actually, scratch *almost* all of above, and just specify bytes as hex sequences, like this:

```
call chansend(b:terminal_job_id, "\x1b\x4f\x41\<cr>")
```

Comment: term_sendkeys is vim’s term api

Comment: You also dont need to do the literal echo from the shell; you can use C-v in vim

Comment: @D.BenKnoble In vim, if you do `C-v` `Up`, it inserts plain text `<Up>` instead of literal byte sequence of `Up` keystroke. And you need the latter to make this work.

Comment: duh /facepalm. I wonder if theres a way to do it, still, as that is a hard workaround

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Turns out, there is! I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks! I was finally able to get the enter key working with your example! I've ditched the up arrow key and resorted to the simpler "!!" built-in. See my answer.

Comment: @Rich Yep, `"\x##"` works as well. Guess that makes my code over-engineered for no reason. Oh well..

Answer (score 1):

the `neovim-lua 0.5 + fish shell + kitty terminal` solution for this is

```lua
vim.cmd("call chansend(" .. job_id .. ', "\x1b\x5b\x41\\<cr>")')
```

its a different hex code, `^[[A` for the mentioned combination. Took me a while to figure out, so I figured this is the best place to mention it.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: I'm surprised this doesn't work everywhere. \x1b is ESC, \x5b is [, and \x41 is A. That means it's sending ESC[A, which is the cursor up ANSI escape control:  https://gist.github.com/fnky/458719343aabd01cfb17a3a4f7296797#cursor-controls. At the very least it worked for me, too. Thanks for posting!

Comment: I can also do `call chansend(job_id, "\<Esc>[A\<CR>")` which makes it slightly clearer, at least for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had been wanting to do the same thing. Your question helped so much! I wrote a super small plugin that does just this:
https://gist.github.com/cowlicks/5d70685346bf341a71f26e564b795a76

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).